# If a regular space is a countable union of compact subspaces then is it paracompact?

Tags: general-topology, compactness, examples-counterexamples, separation-axioms, paracompactness

If $X$ is a regular space such that it is a countable union of compact subspaces then is it true that $X$ is paracompact ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Such a space is even Lindelöf, so even strongly paracompact (see Engelking, general Topology, for that notion)

Comment: okay ... is that fact also in Engelking ?

Comment: @SaunDev indeed, so it is.

Comment: @SaunDev. Being Lindelöf is obvious I'd say.

Comment: @SaunDev: If you want to investigate further, it may be useful to know that what Engelking calls *strongly paracompact* is also known as *hypocompact*.

Comment: @Saundev it's defined as that every open cover has a star finite refinement.